# Long-press followed by swipe on different controls in Android app

Tags: android, xamarin, swipe, imagebutton, seekbar

I have an image button which has a click and a long click hooked up to it. On a long-press I display a custom vertical seek bar. All the functionality I need is fully functional with the exception of one requirement. I need to be able to start a swipe-up gesture after long pressing the button without lifting my finger. The slide gesture should operate on my vertical seek bar. I can already do this but I need to lift my finger after long pressing the button. Here's what I have so far

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private ImageButton m_jump1;
    private VerticalSeekBar m_seekUp;
    private TextView m_progress;
    private string[] m_values;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        m_values = new[] { "-5 Sec", "-15 Sec", "-1 Min", "-5 Min", "-15 Min", "-30 Min", "-1 H", "-6 H" };

        m_seekUp = FindViewById<VerticalSeekBar>(Resource.Id.SliderUp);
        m_seekUp.ProgressChanged += OnProgressChanged;
        m_seekUp.Touch += OnTouch;
        m_jump1 = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.Jump1);
        m_jump1.Click += OnJump;
        m_jump1.LongClick += OnShowSliderUp;
        m_progress = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ProgressTextView);
        m_progress.Text = m_values[m_seekUp.Progress];
    }

    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
        {
            if (m_seekUp.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible)
            {
                var rect = new Rect(m_seekUp.Left, m_seekUp.Top, m_seekUp.Right, m_seekUp.Bottom);
                if (!rect.Contains((int)e.RawX, (int)e.RawY))
                {
                    m_seekUp.Progress = 1;
                    m_seekUp.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                    m_progress.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                }
            }
        }
        return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
    }

    private void OnJump(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (m_seekUp.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible)
        {
            m_seekUp.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            m_progress.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        }
    }

    private void OnShowSliderUp(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (m_seekUp.Visibility == ViewStates.Invisible)
        {
            m_seekUp.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            m_progress.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
    }

    private void OnTouch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Event.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                m_seekUp.Progress = 1;
                m_seekUp.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                m_progress.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                e.Handled = false;
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                e.Handled = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnProgressChanged(object sender, SeekBar.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Progress)
        {
            case 0:
                m_progress.Text = m_values[e.Progress];
                break;
            case 1:
                m_progress.Text = m_values[e.Progress];
                break;
            case 2:
                m_progress.Text = m_values[e.Progress];
                break;
            case 3:
                m_progress.Text = m_values[e.Progress];
                break;
            case 4:
                m_progress.Text = m_values[e.Progress];
                break;
            case 5:
                m_progress.Text = m_values[e.Progress];
                break;
            case 6:
                m_progress.Text = m_values[e.Progress];
                break;
            case 7:
                m_progress.Text = m_values[e.Progress];
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

I am working with Xamarin but any answers in Java will work too, I will convert the code myself

Comment: use a GestureDetector to detect long press and fling (swipe) gestures

Comment: I thought of that but i'm not sure whether the progressChanged and Touch events will be fired on my slider?? Care to share some code

Comment: i don't have any code,  just proposed an idea,  you need to implement the code

Comment: I tried what you suggested but the problem is that the OnProgressChanged event is never fired. I'm able to delegate the Touch events from the button to the seek barbut it doesn't seem to register the swipes over the seek bar